# boost::asio async_read/async_send are bypassing it's handler

Tags: c++, boost, synchronization, boost-asio

I made a static-lib. And I created this three classes in

Connection Class

```
#ifndef _CONNECTION_H_
#define _CONNECTION_H_

#include <boost/array.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include "ByteBuffer.h"

class Connection: public boost::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<Connection> pointer;

  explicit Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service);
  virtual ~Connection();
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket();

  virtual void OnConnected()=0;
  virtual void Send(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buffer, int length);
  void Receive();
  void Disconnect();
  bool connected;
protected:
  virtual void OnReceived(ByteBuffer &b) = 0;

private:
  void handle_Receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred );
  void handle_Send(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred);

  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
  bool disconnecting;
  boost::array<uint8_t, 1000> read_buffer_;
};

#endif


#include "Connection.h"


Connection::Connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    :socket_(io_service),disconnecting(false),connected(false){}

Connection::~Connection(){}


boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& Connection::socket(){
    return socket_;
}

void Connection::Send(std::shared_ptr<uint8_t> buf, int length){
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(buf.get(),length),
            boost::bind(&Connection::handle_Send, shared_from_this(), boost::asio::placeholders::error, boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Connection::handle_Send(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred){

}

void Connection::Receive(){
     boost::asio::async_read(socket_,boost::asio::buffer(this->read_buffer_),
        boost::bind(&Connection::handle_Receive, shared_from_this(),boost::asio::placeholders::error,boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
}

void Connection::handle_Receive(const boost::system::error_code& error, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
{
  if(!error)
  {
      if(bytes_transferred <=0){
            this->Disconnect();
      }else{
```

ByteBuffer b((std::shared_ptr)this->read_buffer_.data(), this->read_buffer_.size());
                this->OnReceived(b);
                this->Receive();}
      }
    }

```
void Connection::Disconnect()
{
    if (!disconnecting) {
        boost::system::error_code ec;
        socket_.shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send,ec);
        socket_.close(ec);
        disconnecting = true;
        std::cout<<"disconnected"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

ConnectionFactory class

```
#pragma once
#include "Connection.h"
class ConnectionFactory
{
public:
    ConnectionFactory(void);
    virtual ~ConnectionFactory(void);

    virtual Connection::pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service) = 0;
};


#include "ConnectionFactory.h"


ConnectionFactory::ConnectionFactory(void)
{
}


ConnectionFactory::~ConnectionFactory(void)
{
}
```

Server Class

```
#ifndef _SERVER_H_
#define _SERVER_H_

#include "Connection.h"
#include "ConnectionFactory.h"

class Server
{
public:
  Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service , std::string ip,short port,boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> factory);
  ~Server();    
private:
  void start_accept();
  void handle_accept(boost::shared_ptr<Connection> conn,const boost::system::error_code& error);

  boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> m_factory;
  boost::asio::io_service &io_service;
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

#endif

#include "Server.h"


Server::Server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service,std::string ip,short port,boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> factory)
    :io_service(io_service), acceptor_(io_service, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string(ip.data()), port)){

        m_factory = factory;
        start_accept();

        std::cout<<"Socket accepting connections..."<<std::endl;
}

Server::~Server()
{
}


void Server::start_accept(){

    boost::shared_ptr<Connection> conn = m_factory->create(this->io_service);
    acceptor_.async_accept(conn->socket(),
        boost::bind(&Server::handle_accept, this,conn,boost::asio::placeholders::error));

}


void Server::handle_accept(boost::shared_ptr<Connection> conn,const boost::system::error_code& error){
    if (!error){
        std::cout<<"on connected"<<std::endl;
        conn->OnConnected();
        conn->Receive();
        start_accept();
    }
    //conn->Disconnect();
}
```

and I drevid from the static-lib and used this classes and it's working perfect

in my main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "auth_proto.h"
#include <Server.h>
#include <ConnectionFactory.h>
#include "AuthConnectionFactory.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    Auth_Setup();
  try
  {
      boost::asio::io_service io_service;
      boost::shared_ptr<ConnectionFactory> fact (new AuthConnectionFactory(io_service));
      Server s(io_service,"5.113.195.156",9959,fact);
      io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I really don't understand what is wrong here , when it comes to the Receive() function it's receive the data from the client but it does not invoking the handle_Receive() method so I can use this data, the behavior that am waiting that it should call the handle_Receive() so I can pass the data to ByteBuffer and use it but that's not happening ......

Comment: It's not obvious to me where you are having problems. What behavior do you currently see? What is the expected behavior? You should also take some time to form complete sentences and correct capitalization and punctuation in your question. Lastly, posting code on external websites is generally frowned upon, it promotes link rot. Please include all of the relevant code in your question to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Sam Miller i updated the question ,as i said the Receive method should pass the data to handel_Recive() method so i can use this data and pass it to the ByteBuffer, but the Recevie() method is not invoking the hnadel_Receive()...

Comment: @Mixed what have you done to debug the problem? How many bytes does the server expect to receive? How many bytes does the client send? How are you testing this?

Comment: @Sam Miller using Packet Handler the serevr should receive a Packet of lenght (ushort)52 and encrypted data so i pass this Packet through the OnReceive() method so i can decrypt it and use it

Comment: @Mixed TCP sockets operate on streams of data, not packets. Again, how many bytes do you instruct async_read to expect?

Comment: @Mixed which method in your code calls `async_read` with a mutable buffer of size 20? I see `Connection::Receive()`, which uses a `boost::array` of 1000 elements.

Comment: @Sam Miller yeah i was using vector but when i asked about the async_read someone told me that i should use boost::array , so if the issue becuase of boost::array then what should i use instead considering that in the future i may recieve like data of 265 byets or something

Comment: @Mixed it's not realistic to give advice for such a general question. It depends entirely on the protocol in use by your application. How have you framed your messages between the client and server?

Comment: @Sam Miller it's kinda hard to explain but the buffer should be unit8_t when i was working with the normal winsock2 i was using `uint8_t* buffer = new uint8_t[1000];` thats all i need , but am kinda new with boost::asio so i dont know how should my buffer looks like.

Comment: @Mixed that doesn't answer the question. At its very basic level, your server needs to know how many bytes to read so it can act upon the message. What are you trying to do exactly? What's the goal of this server?

Comment: @Sam Miller it's a game server which i cant really define the bytes of what am receving , it's only the Packet Handler which control the packets which am sending and receiving , but still that wont make the Recive() method not invoking the handel_Receive() , what is the byte has to do with the invoking of onther method?

Comment: @Mixed Don't think of your communication in terms of packets. TCP sockets operate on contiguous streams of data. You need to frame the messages sent between your server and clients. One way to accomplish this is a fixed length header prior to sending each message. This header would include the number of bytes to expect in the message, so your server knows how many bytes to read.

Comment: @Sam Miller so you are telling me that the Receive() not invoking it's handler because the server doesnot know how many bytes to receive? 0.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`boost::asio::async_read` seems to call the read handler only when it reaches the "amount of data" passed to it.

Quoting boost's 1.46.0 reference:

> async_read
>
> Start an asynchronous operation to read a *certain* amount of data from a stream.

So as a solution, use `socket_.async_read_some` instead of `boost::asio::async_read` if you wish to be informed of any arbitrary amount of data received.

Another solution, as Sam Miller was trying to say in the comments, you can add a fixed size header containing the number of bytes incoming before each frame you're supposed to receive, read the header then call `boost::asio::async_read` with the previously extracted number.

Comment: @Khaled Nassar nah i updated it in the project but i forgot to update it here, the problem is Receive() is not CALLING handle_Receive().

Comment: @Khaled Nassar am calling Receive() from the server class

Comment: @MixedCoder Your words imply that you pinned down the problem, might wanna update it in the question or post an answer with the solution?

Comment: @Khaled Nassar i upadated the question and it has nothing to do with the invoking of handle_Receive()....